# Valid file types for iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I find many similar question but i didn't get solution for this.

Is it possible to upload some file like image, document, zip file to upload on iCloud programmatically?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html

Comment: @jbat100, i have seen all the document but they have write only document, not anything else like video, audio, zip, image, etc. My question is, "can we you upload video, audio, zip, image, etc to iCloud or not?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See table 4-1 in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html):

> **How do you manage the data?**  Manage files and directores using the
>   NSFileManager class. Open, close, read, and write files using standard
>   file system routines.

So if you can create a file, you can store it in iCloud. But remember there's a finite, relatively small amount of space available.

Comment: But Suppose i have integrate in-app purchase and i don't want user to buy in all its iDevice so what i want is downloaded zip upload to user iCloud and user can access it in all his/her iDevice.

Comment: You want to upload files to iCloud _outside_ your iOS app? It's really not clear from your question that that is what you want to do.

Comment: I had develop one application in which i want to create functionality which will upload file (ZIP which is downloaded from server) to iCloud. Is it possible (within application only)?

Comment: You can upload any file to iCloud. It doesn't matter where the file originally came from. (But, if you can just download the file, what's the point of saving it to iCloud?)

Comment: Can i upload video files (size 5mb) from ios custom  application

Comment: @RaviJSS Well, the Facebook app, among many, many others, suggests that, yes, it's possible.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Sorry actually i want to ask the can i upload video file to iCloud from custom ios application

Comment: @RaviJSS A video file is just a file.

Comment: @StephenDarlington can you tell me  how to upload video file to icloud from ios programming , my file is in documentry folder

Comment: @RaviJSS That's beyond the scope of this question. And it's covered quite well in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud can handle all kinds of files. So if you want rot use an obscure file format or invent your own, go for it. It only can to be converted into a byte stream/NSData, but then again, what isn't?

Check this tutorial walkthrough app. It shows how to create, modify and delete files for iCloud.

http://github.com/lichtschlag/iCloudPlayground